# Dual NIC silently rejecting all incoming traffic from one interface

Tags: ethernet, netplan, ip, routing, nic

In my server, I have two ethernet cards:

- `enp0s17`, local IP `192.168.0.7`, router's public address `x.x.x.x`, netmask `255.255.255.255`
- `enp0s18`, local IP `172.16.0.7`, router's public address `y.y.y.y`, netmask `255.255.255.0`

On both networks, **any incoming traffic** of the two public IPs is **routed to the server**. So, actually any SSH, HTTP etc. going to `x.x.x.x` should be forwarded to `192.168.0.7` and any traffic to `y.y.y.y` should be forwarded to `172.16.0.7`.

Unfortunately, this is only working for **one of them at once**. Sometimes (after dis- and reconnecting the server to internet e.g. after reboot) this works for `enp0s17` and sometimes for `enp0s18` but **never for both** at the same time. (So, both routers are routing properly, seems to be an issue of the server.)

Same issue applies for outgoing traffic tested with `curl --interface enp0s1X ...`.

On the other hand, any **local traffic** is routing properly. In both networks, the server is always available on it's local IPs.

**Does anyone have an idea what might cause this issue or how to solve it?**

*For testing purpose I completely disabled the firewall, so, this shouldn't be the problem.*

*(Both interfaces are using IPv6 prefix delegation too but I just left it out as it's working properly.)*

Both routers are Ubiquiti EdgeRouters. IPs are statically given by the DHCP servers on the routers. Network configuration is done using `netplan`. Using Ubuntu 20.04.

My `netplan` config:

```yaml
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: networkd
    ethernets:
       enp0s17:
          dhcp4: yes
          dhcp6: yes
       enp0s18:
          dhcp4: yes
          dhcp6: yes
```